# Save entire DOM in mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, dom

I am not sure if this is possible, but I am looking for a way to save the entire state of my webpage without explicitly saving each element to a database.

For example, I dynamically create buttons, checkboxes, text etc. until the webpage looks as it needs. Can I save the DOM as a string, or blob in a database, and parse it later the get the webpage back?

I have tried things like:

```
var doc = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

Then save the string to database but it doesn't work.

I am using an AJAX call to a PHP script to write to mysql:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'connect/database.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {functionname: 'connect_to_database', arguments: [user_id, user, doc] },
            success: function (obj, textstatus) {
            if( !('error' in obj) ) {
            }
            else {
            console.log(obj.error);
            }
            }
            });
```

PHP looks like:

```
  // connection script
                    $servername = "XXX";
                    $username = "XXX";
                    $password = "XXX";
                    $dbname = "XXX";

                    $user_id = $_POST['arguments'][0];
                    $user = $_POST['arguments'][1];
                    $string = $_POST['arguments'][2];

                    // create connection
                    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                    // Check connection
                    if ($conn->connect_error) {
                        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                    }

                      $sql = "INSERT INTO table (user_id, user, string) VALUES ('$user_id', '$user', '$string')";
                    # $sql = "UPDATE crows_nest SET json_string='$configuration' WHERE user = '$user'";

                    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                        echo "New record created successfully";
                    } else {
                        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                    }
                    $conn->close();
```

Comment: What doesn't work? `document.documentElement.outerHTML` returns a string. Just dump it into database.

Comment: @thangngoc89 it isn't saving. I set the mysql type to longtext.

Comment: JSON.stringify takes an object and convert it to string. No need to do that since the doc is already a string

Comment: gotcha, thanks. Any reason it wouldn't save? Trying mediumtext also...no go.

Comment: How are you sending it to the server?

Comment: Making an AJAX call to a PHP script. I'll update question..

Comment: When you say it is not working what do you mean? Are there any errors? Did you turn on SQL logging to see if you SQL is even running on MySQL?

Comment: Use a prepared statement instead of substituting variables into `$sql`. There are probably quotes in `$string`, so you're getting a syntax error.

Comment: Yes, I was just going to say that is a very dangerous way of saving data to the database. Someone could easily use SQL injection. Absolutely use a prepared statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a prepared statement to prevent problems with special characters in the document string.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table (user_id, user, string) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("iss", $user_id, $user, $string);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "New record created successfully.";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you.