# load website from DOM string

Tags: javascript, string, dom

I save my website DOM as a single string. I now want to read that string from the database and load the website. Is there a way for javascript to parse/render a complete page from a string version of the DOM and load as the current webpage?

I am trying something like this but am not sure how to load the result as the webpage:

```
parser = new DOMParser();
doc = parser.parseFromString(my_dom_as_string, "text/xml");
```

Comment: This is a strange way to create a website and without more information we are just shooting in the dark. When you store a page what exactly are you storing? Are you storing entire document or just the part inside body? Is the string escaped?

Comment: @TeaCode See his previous question, which was about saving the DOM: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36320448/save-entire-dom-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to parse it. Just write it directly into the document's `outerHTML`, and the browser will parse it.

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML = my_dom_as_string;
```

This is just the opposite of what you did to store it in your [previous question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36320448/save-entire-dom-in-mysql)

Comment: Yes of course its the opposite. I want to save the webpage as a string....then read it from the database. For example, different users can have different DOMs based on how their page was dynamically created.

Comment: I am trying your method, but the page doesn't load.

Comment: innerHTML will show the right content...but none of the CSS or Javascript appears.

Comment: Ahh, you can't assign to `outerHTML` if the element doesn't have a parent. Maybe instead of saving the document's outerHTML, you should save the innerHTML, and then restore that.

Comment: Getting there...but there is still no CSS or JS available on the loaded content. Is there a way to load that after the DOM has been loaded?

Comment: Yeah, scripts aren't executed when assigned with `innerHTML`. You have to call `document.createElement('script')` explicitly to do that. Can you use jQuery? It's `.html()` method looks for scripts and executes them. Not sure about CSS, though.

Comment: Or could you do this on the server instead of the client? The server can simply do `echo $string;` to create the page.